# DropDownList selection is posting as null ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownList that is populated from a database table that has one column called "IncidentNumber". When using this DropDownList to post as part of a form into a different database table the application is throwing an exception because the DropDownList selection is posting as null. Any help here would be much appreciated!

Controller Action

```
 var items = db.ViewIncidentNumbers.ToList();
        if (items != null)
        {
            ViewBag.data = items;
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (LogInformationEntities4 dc = new LogInformationEntities4())
            {
                dc.LandLostPersonDetails.Add(land);
                dc.SaveChanges();
            }
         }
```

Code that is in the View

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Incident_Number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("IncidentNumber", new SelectList(ViewBag.data, "IncidentNumber", "IncidentNumber"))
        </div>
    </div>
```

EDIT:
Incident Number class:

```
    public partial class IncidentNumber
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string IncidentNumber1 { get; set; }
}
```

My controller currently looks like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult NewLandMissingPerson()
    {
        string teamsession = string.Empty;
        string username = string.Empty;
        teamsession = Convert.ToString(Session["Callsign"]);
        username = Convert.ToString(Session["Username"]);

        LogInformationEntities4 dc = new LogInformationEntities4();
        var items = dc.IncidentNumbers.ToList();
        ViewBag.data = new SelectList(items.Select(x => new { Text = x.IncidentNumber1, Id = x.Id, Value = x.IncidentNumber1 }).ToList());

        return View();
    }

        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult NewLandMissingPerson(LandLostPersonDetail land)
    {
        LogInformationEntities4 db = new LogInformationEntities4();
        bool Status = false;
        string response = "";

        var items = db.IncidentNumbers.ToList();
        ViewBag.data = new SelectList(items.Select(x => new { Text=x.IncidentNumber1, Id=x.Id, Value = x.IncidentNumber1 }).ToList());
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (LogInformationEntities4 dc = new LogInformationEntities4())
            {
                dc.LandLostPersonDetails.Add(land);
                dc.SaveChanges();
                response = "New Missing Person Log Added.";
                Status = true;
            }
        }
```

And the view currently looks like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Incident_Number, new SelectList(ViewBag.data, "IncidentNumber1", "IncidentNumber1"))
```

I am currently getting an exception which says that IncidentNumber1 does not exist in System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem

Comment: What is the resulting rendered HTML for the drop down list?  What is the controller action to which it is posting?  Specifically which posted value in that action is null?

Comment: The Controller action is called NewLandMissingPerson. That value that is being posted as null is the Incident_Number value. The rendered HTML for the drop down list brings each of the values that are in the database.

Comment: Can you post the class that contains the property `IncidentNumber`, and also post the `HttpPost` controller action where you're trying to submit to, please.

Comment: I have edited the post to show this now

Comment: Can you post the entire controller actionresult please?

Comment: Edited it to show the whole actionresult

Comment: Okay, so you're showing that in your `HttpPost` actionresult, you're expecting a `LandLostPersonDetail` object... does that class have a property called `IncidentNumber` or is `IncidentNumber` something you want submitted separately?

Comment: LandLostPersonDetail has a property called Incident_Number which is where I want to insert the value selected from the dropdownlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, based from the comments, I think this will help.

Since, `IncidentNumber` is a property of `LandLostPersonDetail` class, then you should use `DropDownListFor` instead of `DropDownList`.  `DropDownListFor` allows for client-side validation based on your model.. so if in your `LandLostPersonDetail` class.. let's say that `IncidentNumber` is required.. then if there is no value for that when the form is submitted then validation will occur on the client-side rather than having to wait and go to `if (ModelState.IsValid)` on the server-side.

Here is what I recommend changing:

**In your HttpGet Action**

```
ViewBag.IncidentNumberSelection = new SelectList(db.IncidentNumbers.ToList(), "IncidentNumber1", "IncidentNumber1");
```

**In your View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Incident_Number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Incident_Number,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.IncidentNumberSelection, "-- Select Incident Number --", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, in your `HttpPost` actionresult.. you will no longer need:

```
var items = db.IncidentNumbers.ToList();
ViewBag.data = new SelectList(items.Select(x => new { Text=x.IncidentNumber1, Id=x.Id, Value = x.IncidentNumber1 }).ToList());
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I had to change the Incident_Number property to a IEnumerable<SelectListItem> as well but it is working now after this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IncidentNumber, new SelectList(ViewBag.data, "IncidentNumber", "IncidentNumber"))
```

In Controller you have to access with **IncidentNumber** property